# "Protocol Buffers" a single thing but with a plural title?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

On its official [website](https://protobuf.dev/overview/), we read

> Protocol Buffers are a language-neutral, platform-neutral extensible mechanism for serializing structured data.

While this is a single protocol, the name is Protocol Buffers. Can you explain?

Comment: It’s not used as a singular word. Your quote begins “Protocol buffers **are**…” compare to “Scissors are a tool for cutting paper, fabric, and similar thin materials.”

Comment: I've closed this based on what I think you're asking, but if that's not right, you need to [edit] to make your question clearer.

Comment: @Laurel can you reopen it now.